# Django:No module named django.core.management

Tags: python, django

I am a Django newbie and want to explore the power of this famous framework.

After all setups I ran

`sudo python manage.py syncdb`,

and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I use virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, and I activated my working virtualenv by issuing a `workon` command.

Also, when I ran `which python`, I got this:

`/home/myname/Envs/EnvName/bin/python`,

and `pip freeze| grep - django`  returns:

```
Django==1.5.4
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
```

The first line of my manage.py is `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Also

`python2.7 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"`

gives

`/home/myname/Envs/EnvName/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

and in this directory, I do see a folder named django.

So I guess I am really stuck, anyone please?

Comment: One of your problems is you are using `sudo`.

Answer (score 8):

This first line its probably making it use your python from `/usr/bin/env`.

You could try two things in this case:

1) If you didn't already, you should activate your virtualenv and then install Django:

```
source /home/myname/Envs/EnvName/bin/activate
pip install django
```

2) Remove first line of manage.py which I don't thing would be a problem since you are using `python manage.py ...`, unless you didn't `activated` your virtualenv before.

---

UPDATE:

There is really nothing more that what it's saying. Python couldn't find django, so you just need to `activate` (which I think you already did) and `pip install django`.

---

ANOTHER UPDATE:

Your problem its actually simpler to solve. You are trying `sudo python manage.py syncdb` and when you do using sudo you are not accessing python from `virtualenv`, so just remove sudo and everything should run.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but like I said, I have my virtualenv activated and django installed, `pip install django` gives `requirements already satisfied`

Comment: Sorry, didn't really look at your first line. Your problem its much simpler to solve. Look at the ANOTHER UPDATE part of my answer.

Comment: if i just ran `python manage.py syncdb`, i got `OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'projecr_database'")
`

Comment: This is a problem on DATABASES var from your settings. At least you know its finding django now because you are using python command from within your virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

system.

Maybe you already fix it out. But I post this for later fellows.

try:

> `which python
>   sudo which python`

after you see the different. 
you are able to do:(with you env activated: source activate)

> sudo `which python` manage.py shell

hope helps

cheers