# Python Error: No module named django.core.management

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

First time here!
And first time with Django also!
I read same issue here on StackOverFlow, e.g: [Django:No module named django.core.management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342896/djangono-module-named-django-core-management)   but without any result

Purpose:
Install a Django app (based on 1.5.1 on windows 8

I have + tested (e.g: pip --version):

- Python 2.7
- Pip 1.5.6
- Virtualenv 1.11.6

I followed the instructions, and when I run:

> python manage.py runserver

P.S:
I created my env,

```
$ virtualenv --distribute myenv
```

and activate it using:

```
source myenv/Scripts/activate
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Any help how to debug the issue?

PPS: Please read the comments bellow!

Regards

Comment: have you activated your env `source env/bin/activate` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Module named django.core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312549/no-module-named-django-core)

Comment: @ChristianBerendt I mentioned that I did a hug research here in Stackoverflow and found many similar issues, but without any results for my case!

Comment: @PepperoniPizza I have `source env/Scripts/activate` instead of `source env/bin/activate` AND yes I did!

Comment: What does "pip freeze" say?

Comment: @WanderNauta `pip freeze` doesn't return anything

Comment: @RosemanPy Then you haven't actually installed Django. Try "pip install django".

Comment: @WanderNauta Django is installed via `$ pip install -r install.txt` which it contains django and other tools like `django-authtool`

Comment: @RosemanPy Make sure you're calling pip with the virtualenv activated.

Comment: @WanderNauta True, I can see `(myenv)` bellow each line, so yes its activated!

Comment: but maybe you haven't installed django ON the env, try running without using the virtualenv.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza I deactivate `virtualenv ` and run the server again via ` python manage.py runserver` , I got the same error mention in my post above!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have django installed in your virtual environment.

Just do this: `pip install django`

In your case, to make sure the right one pip is used: `env/Scripts/pip install django`

Virtual environment is isolated "python + packages folder", so you need to install your packages again, but **for this virtual evironment**.

It is obvious, because you have exception at 8 line of manage.py, which tries to import special django function to run command-line commands.

Comment: Is there a way to debug this? Do I need to add any path to the virtualenv?

Comment: I think, you are using Windows and your PATH contains global python scripts, but no venv scripts, so you run different pip, which is bad. Try to run `env/Scripts/pip install django`

Comment: This is good! This means, it have found django, so you need to install other missing libs: `env/Scripts/pip install -r install.txt` (since you have install.txt).

Comment: Thank you so much, I got this 
`User@Rosemanpy /c/wamp/www/env (master)
$ env/Scripts/pip install -r install.txt
sh.exe": env/Scripts/pip: No such file or directory
(env)`

Comment: Oh, have you done `cd env`? You are in `env` directory, so try to `Scripts/pip install -r install.txt`. And make sure you have `install.txt` in **current** directory or you should provide full path to it.

Comment: P.S: my django app name is the same as my `env` name, is this can cause an issue?

Comment: You can call it whatever. To install needed packages in needed environment, you should provide **path to pip**(which locates in Scipts directory of your environment, I suppose) and **path to install.txt**(which should be located in your project). Then, make a command like this: `myenvpippath install -r myinstalltxtpath`.

Comment: Oh this is gooood! Everything is ok. But it seems you have old project  (it requires django 1.5.1!). It cannot find needed version of PIL package, so set it up manualy: `pip install PIL`. Latest version will be fine, I guess.

Comment: I learned a ton today, Thank you so much, my latest command returns this  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SHq1U3TU

Comment: I've installed PIL manually via http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ (version 2.7) but still get the error

Comment: I did `pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL` and it worked, when I run the server from the (app directory) I got this error again http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ww4HgAiQ

Comment: Good. By the way, this error can be possible because PIL is old and most developers prefer Pillow, which has same API.

Comment: Or maybe it tries to find package in some local repo.. dunno.